# CSS Layout Divs within Divs

Tags: css

I am trying to layout 12 divs within another div. It seems that the margin-left is not working for them. They appear in a vertical column rather beside eachother.[image]

```
div id="wrapper">
<div id="mydiv">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
wrapper{
width:952px;
height:602px;
margin: 0px auto;
position:relative;
}
#mydiv{
position:absolute;
left:150px;
width:600px;
height:375px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding:10px;
color:#FF0080;
background-color:#FF0000;

}
#mydiv div{
width:180px;
height:100px;
background-color:#000000;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: The margin left works out as expected. Perhaps you should explain what you try to do.

Comment: do you really need absolute positioning?

Comment: Hi yes I do need absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to float the divs if you want them to appear side-by-side:

> **Fix**: specified class instead of style for inline styling.

```
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
    Hello
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
    World!
</div>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTtcn/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

You need either:

```css
#mydiv div {float: left;}
```

or

```css
#mydiv div {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: +1 for inline-block. Floats were not originally meant for layout.

Answer (score 1):

Have #mydiv which holds all your other divs. Then #divleft and #divright. With float's defined as such:

```
#divleft {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#divright {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```